# background image in navigationbar go to the top of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, navigationbar

Why background image appear under the top line, where I can see time, charge of battery and other information. This line in other app is black. I mean next

[image]

So I create navigation controller in storyboard

[image]

So i have next code, first it was in viewDidLoad

[image]

my backGroundLayer is 320x44

Answer (score 1):

The status bar (reception, time, battery charge, etc.) and the navigation bar (title, back buttons, etc.) are two completely different areas in an app. [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage] only controls the appearance of the navigation bar. If you want to change the appearance of the status bar, click on your Xcode project and go to iPhone/iPod Deployment Info > Status Bar. There, you can change the appearance of the status bar, including the colour, background, and visibility.

Comment: I don't want change color of status bar, but it changed itself. I want to understand what is problem. I think I made mistake with navigation controller

Comment: Try relocating the code to AppDelegate.m, and place it under the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar changes to match the color of the background image set. If you do not want this to occur you can set the status bar style to black translucent using the code below or change it in your Xcode project under iPhone/iPod Deployment Info -> Status Bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];
```